# Unite SVG Group of Circles to Single Path

Tags: svg, adobe-illustrator, snap.svg

I may have titled the question wrong because I don't really know how to ask what I am looking to do. Let me explain it though.

I have a large SVG file with ~700 groups(`<g></g>`). Each group has a different amount of `<circle>` paths with different locations, all circles within a group have the same radius and color. At the moment, every circle is it's own path which is making the file way too large to do anything with as there are hundreds of thousands of these circles. I need to combine all of the circles within each group into one path. I have figured out how to do this in Adobe Illustrator, the way I did it was to select all circles within a group from the layers panel and then use Windows>Pathfinder>Unite which merges the circles into one shape. However, I would have to go through every single group one-by-one which is too much. Is there anything that will do something like this for me? I don't want to spend days going through each and every group Uniting them...

An example of my SVG:

```
<g fill="#71b190" stroke="#71b190" stroke-width=".1">
    <circle cx="-505753.529" cy="-173234.268" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505749.628" cy="-173234.226" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505747.843" cy="-173234.215" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505742.67" cy="-173234.194" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505706.735" cy="-173234.09" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505703.787" cy="-173309.959" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505703.526" cy="-173237.828" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505702.73" cy="-173238.572" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505702.316" cy="-173238.744" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505701.269" cy="-173239.237" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505701.002" cy="-173262.186" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505701.002" cy="-173262.212" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505700.939" cy="-173254.578" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505700.934" cy="-173254.835" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505700.923" cy="-173250.798" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505700.923" cy="-173251.264" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505700.918" cy="-173258.374" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505700.913" cy="-173241.781" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505700.913" cy="-173242.739" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505700.913" cy="-173258.426" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505700.902" cy="-173245.551" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505700.897" cy="-173246.3" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505698.138" cy="-173234.048" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505692.127" cy="-173233.948" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505691.802" cy="-173233.932" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505691.258" cy="-173233.906" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505689.216" cy="-173292.806" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505688.697" cy="-173238.723" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505688.357" cy="-173233.775" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505688.273" cy="-173236.268" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505688.205" cy="-173244.734" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505688.174" cy="-173246.776" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505688.142" cy="-173248.818" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505688.127" cy="-173249.918" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505688.111" cy="-173251.018" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505688.095" cy="-173251.96" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505688.079" cy="-173253.06" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505688.064" cy="-173254.159" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505688.048" cy="-173255.102" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505688.032" cy="-173256.201" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505688.001" cy="-173258.243" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505686.818" cy="-173243.561" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505683.058" cy="-173243.368" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505681.178" cy="-173243.268" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505679.299" cy="-173243.148" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505678.346" cy="-173301.278" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505665.905" cy="-173295.22" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505665.905" cy="-173296.743" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505665.905" cy="-173296.969" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505665.905" cy="-173299.524" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505665.905" cy="-173299.707" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505665.518" cy="-173309.64" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505665.203" cy="-173285.193" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505665.125" cy="-173419.538" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505664.298" cy="-173317.331" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505664.177" cy="-173285.25" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505663.722" cy="-173488.878" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505663.449" cy="-173488.401" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505663.041" cy="-173419.501" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505662.643" cy="-173311.064" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505661.962" cy="-173311.048" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505661.57" cy="-173393.248" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505661.496" cy="-173394.248" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505661.481" cy="-173394.667" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505661.475" cy="-173390.813" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505661.402" cy="-173396.342" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505661.287" cy="-173398.945" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505661.172" cy="-173401.463" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505661.13" cy="-173402.301" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505660.711" cy="-173311.011" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505660.465" cy="-173299.786" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505659.789" cy="-173388.389" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505659.035" cy="-173286.559" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505658.868" cy="-173419.423" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505658.334" cy="-173386.907" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505658.287" cy="-173479.752" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505657.978" cy="-173386.546" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505657.255" cy="-173394.101" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505656.862" cy="-173385.394" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505656.779" cy="-173419.381" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505656.459" cy="-173299.786" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505656.339" cy="-173384.818" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505655.889" cy="-173310.875" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505655.229" cy="-173310.86" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505654.847" cy="-173402.39" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505654.339" cy="-173289.24" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505654.339" cy="-173472.966" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505653.894" cy="-173310.818" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505653.726" cy="-173316.577" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505653.658" cy="-173381.975" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505653.36" cy="-173393.939" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505653.129" cy="-173381.425" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505652.606" cy="-173419.297" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505652.349" cy="-173380.488" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505652.161" cy="-173402.28" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505652.098" cy="-173246.996" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505652.04" cy="-173229.272" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505651.883" cy="-173310.76" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505651.846" cy="-173246.907" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505651.265" cy="-173402.243" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505650.867" cy="-173230.812" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505650.37" cy="-173392.761" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505650.338" cy="-173378.226" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505650.255" cy="-173390.541" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505650.208" cy="-173295.759" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505650.066" cy="-173378.084" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505650.009" cy="-173402.191" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505649.893" cy="-173291.963" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505649.836" cy="-173236.153" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505649.689" cy="-173244.923" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505649.689" cy="-173298.199" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505649.652" cy="-173402.18" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505649.59" cy="-173298.545" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505649.145" cy="-173387.734" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505649.118" cy="-173393.756" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505649.103" cy="-173310.682" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505648.899" cy="-173377.477" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505648.862" cy="-173301.053" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505648.569" cy="-173310.655" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505648.453" cy="-173316.603" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505648.438" cy="-173292.832" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505648.433" cy="-173419.203" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505648.317" cy="-173228.372" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505647.684" cy="-173402.097" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505647.322" cy="-173402.081" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505647.307" cy="-173377.043" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505647.265" cy="-173377.011" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505647.228" cy="-173227.864" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505646.747" cy="-173393.672" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505646.427" cy="-173402.05" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505646.349" cy="-173419.156" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505645.532" cy="-173402.013" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505643.594" cy="-173376.618" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505643.296" cy="-173317.509" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505643.286" cy="-173317.509" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505643.055" cy="-173298.503" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505642.84" cy="-173410.171" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505642.82" cy="-173376.467" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505642.772" cy="-173300.733" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505642.448" cy="-173304.618" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505642.196" cy="-173430.785" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505642.155" cy="-173227.639" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505642.024" cy="-173315.127" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505641.956" cy="-173316.975" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505641.919" cy="-173317.74" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505641.767" cy="-173320.049" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505641.516" cy="-173325.468" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505641.401" cy="-173330.207" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505640.537" cy="-173358.779" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505640.469" cy="-173359.811" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505640.374" cy="-173361.633" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505640.212" cy="-173364.445" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505640.202" cy="-173234.76" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505640.139" cy="-173350.894" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505640.102" cy="-173367.283" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505640.05" cy="-173368.681" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505640.039" cy="-173351.402" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505639.605" cy="-173227.576" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505639.589" cy="-173227.576" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505635.117" cy="-173336.458" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505634.84" cy="-173337.537" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505634.782" cy="-173337.746" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505634.725" cy="-173339.024" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505634.693" cy="-173338.459" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505634.678" cy="-173338.27" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505634.222" cy="-173330.5" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505634.128" cy="-173327.526" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505634.054" cy="-173327.17" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505633.918" cy="-173332.851" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505632.238" cy="-173325.609" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505631.73" cy="-173263.872" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505631.724" cy="-173266.338" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505631.714" cy="-173272.255" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505631.704" cy="-173276.203" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505631.704" cy="-173276.349" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505631.677" cy="-173257.264" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505631.662" cy="-173254.986" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505631.588" cy="-173252.311" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505631.573" cy="-173286.418" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505631.52" cy="-173250.96" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505631.478" cy="-173290.455" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505631.478" cy="-173290.544" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505631.379" cy="-173292.864" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505631.332" cy="-173238.341" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505630.447" cy="-173325.704" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505630.389" cy="-173325.698" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505630.154" cy="-173325.683" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505629.761" cy="-173276.407" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505628.117" cy="-173275.888" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505626.593" cy="-173264.542" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505626.274" cy="-173207.878" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505626.201" cy="-173276.103" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505625.415" cy="-173211.193" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505625.389" cy="-173212.533" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505625.295" cy="-173205.957" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505625.284" cy="-173217.978" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505625.232" cy="-173220.748" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505625.179" cy="-173222.801" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505625.075" cy="-173226.963" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505625.049" cy="-173229.094" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505624.975" cy="-173231.576" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505624.829" cy="-173236.53" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505624.583" cy="-173283.423" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505624.394" cy="-173203.051" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505624.279" cy="-173276.318" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505623.206" cy="-173228.958" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505623.169" cy="-173375.487" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505622.954" cy="-173220.403" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505622.944" cy="-173240.142" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505622.902" cy="-173202.873" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505622.886" cy="-173238.875" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505622.881" cy="-173238.949" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505622.677" cy="-173275.637" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505622.52" cy="-173331.772" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505622.488" cy="-173263.469" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505622.462" cy="-173331.584" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505622.404" cy="-173331.395" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505622.342" cy="-173331.207" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505622.169" cy="-173210.35" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505621.645" cy="-173201.831" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505621.509" cy="-173243.849" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505621.357" cy="-173228.901" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505621.127" cy="-173274.831" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505620.671" cy="-173220.052" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505620.614" cy="-173375.299" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505620.556" cy="-173260.039" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505620.399" cy="-173283.266" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505619.75" cy="-173273.836" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505619.713" cy="-173257.18" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505619.582" cy="-173327.819" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505619.42" cy="-173327.248" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505619.336" cy="-173326.966" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505619.258" cy="-173326.678" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505618.865" cy="-173254.316" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505618.86" cy="-173254.295" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505618.849" cy="-173254.264" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505618.828" cy="-173209.486" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505618.519" cy="-173201.396" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505618.394" cy="-173219.706" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505618.331" cy="-173272.857" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505617.781" cy="-173238.65" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505617.661" cy="-173228.812" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505616.891" cy="-173201.82" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505616.734" cy="-173272.113" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505616.111" cy="-173219.355" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505616.1" cy="-173219.355" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505615.812" cy="-173228.738" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505615.802" cy="-173228.738" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505615.577" cy="-173208.637" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505615.566" cy="-173208.637" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505615.54" cy="-173208.627" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505615.257" cy="-173202.244" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505614.964" cy="-173271.715" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505614.854" cy="-173271.694" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505613.561" cy="-173276.396" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505613.404" cy="-173276.627" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505613.399" cy="-173276.632" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505613.383" cy="-173276.653" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505613.378" cy="-173276.663" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505613.205" cy="-173259.673" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505612.796" cy="-173259.652" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505612.692" cy="-173370.906" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505612.576" cy="-173238.409" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505612.388" cy="-173259.631" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505611.995" cy="-173259.61" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505611.98" cy="-173202.192" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505611.608" cy="-173259.62" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505611.597" cy="-173259.62" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505611.566" cy="-173259.62" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505610.424" cy="-173282.936" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505610.168" cy="-173332.453" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505610.121" cy="-173219.408" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505609.969" cy="-173222.298" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505609.55" cy="-173231.288" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505609" cy="-173201.49" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505608.807" cy="-173238.236" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505608.456" cy="-173332.406" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505608.272" cy="-173199.427" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505607.775" cy="-173335.207" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505607.634" cy="-173370.738" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505607.44" cy="-173341.872" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505607.309" cy="-173341.872" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505607.073" cy="-173238.153" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505606.848" cy="-173354.889" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505606.848" cy="-173354.936" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505606.843" cy="-173355.057" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505606.843" cy="-173355.104" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505606.827" cy="-173355.79" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505606.827" cy="-173355.884" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505606.785" cy="-173358.088" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505606.759" cy="-173199.396" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505606.759" cy="-173359.476" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505606.744" cy="-173360.052" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505606.738" cy="-173360.34" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505606.733" cy="-173360.581" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505606.539" cy="-173349.365" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505606.524" cy="-173362.623" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505606.487" cy="-173362.984" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505606.272" cy="-173282.947" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505605.775" cy="-173238.079" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505604.613" cy="-173332.285" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505604.571" cy="-173211.062" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505603.649" cy="-173332.238" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505602.618" cy="-173283.193" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505602.492" cy="-173278.559" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505602.366" cy="-173273.92" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505602.283" cy="-173283.214" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505602.241" cy="-173269.281" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505602.11" cy="-173264.631" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505600.445" cy="-173370.498" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505599.701" cy="-173332.055" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505598.136" cy="-173237.723" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505597.649" cy="-173283.538" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505595.753" cy="-173370.309" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505593.135" cy="-173283.852" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505591.324" cy="-173283.978" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505591.067" cy="-173331.688" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505590.952" cy="-173280.685" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505589.601" cy="-173270.574" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505589.145" cy="-173370.058" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505588.182" cy="-173270.558" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505587.878" cy="-173270.553" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505587.428" cy="-173283.386" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505586.983" cy="-173283.318" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505586.093" cy="-173386.656" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505586.04" cy="-173270.522" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505585.904" cy="-173209.711" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505585.899" cy="-173369.969" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505584.878" cy="-173209.679" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505584.307" cy="-173270.485" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505583.532" cy="-173282.789" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505582.47" cy="-173270.448" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505581.946" cy="-173369.806" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505581.852" cy="-173240.493" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505580.736" cy="-173270.417" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505580.208" cy="-173209.548" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505580.051" cy="-173241.409" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505579.506" cy="-173282.439" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505579.113" cy="-173282.412" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505577.972" cy="-173369.634" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505577.249" cy="-173270.349" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505577.145" cy="-173282.287" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505573.93" cy="-173209.329" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505573.636" cy="-173270.291" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505573.244" cy="-173369.424" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505572.914" cy="-173369.414" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505571.327" cy="-173369.34" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505570.605" cy="-173369.309" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505569.338" cy="-173249.567" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505569.013" cy="-173258.044" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505568.935" cy="-173260.097" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505568.825" cy="-173262.709" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505568.636" cy="-173266.123" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505568.421" cy="-173369.215" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505568.27" cy="-173369.204" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505568.081" cy="-173275.428" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505567.804" cy="-173369.183" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505565.18" cy="-173274.904" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505565.149" cy="-173247.886" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505564.735" cy="-173209.161" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505563.735" cy="-173394.101" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505563.405" cy="-173387.797" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505563.295" cy="-173403.458" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505562.96" cy="-173261.788" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505562.882" cy="-173274.595" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505562.808" cy="-173248.017" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505562.651" cy="-173209.119" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505562.41" cy="-173368.948" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505561.274" cy="-173247.97" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505561.033" cy="-173274.888" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505559.918" cy="-173330.468" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505559.913" cy="-173276.255" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505559.85" cy="-173277.119" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505559.85" cy="-173277.129" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505559.85" cy="-173277.14" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505559.85" cy="-173277.15" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505559.693" cy="-173330.453" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505557.855" cy="-173261.699" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505557.499" cy="-173261.694" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505557.368" cy="-173247.886" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505556.976" cy="-173330.275" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505556.771" cy="-173247.865" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505555.776" cy="-173247.86" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505554.556" cy="-173368.607" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505554.483" cy="-173330.139" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505553.63" cy="-173330.091" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505553.462" cy="-173330.076" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505553.457" cy="-173261.558" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505552.122" cy="-173261.233" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505551.886" cy="-173247.803" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505551.792" cy="-173247.797" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505550.959" cy="-173399.18" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505550.315" cy="-173260.17" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505550.268" cy="-173247.782" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505549.682" cy="-173259.804" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505549.472" cy="-173259.594" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505549.268" cy="-173247.761" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505548.75" cy="-173257.924" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505548.739" cy="-173256.924" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505548.504" cy="-173256.07" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505548.42" cy="-173256.442" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505548.294" cy="-173387.122" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505548.19" cy="-173255.222" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505548.059" cy="-173329.756" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505546.226" cy="-173329.641" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505545.655" cy="-173329.599" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505544.263" cy="-173247.687" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505543.985" cy="-173249.913" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505543.357" cy="-173249.19" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505542.828" cy="-173386.912" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505540.425" cy="-173208.423" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505540.388" cy="-173208.418" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505539.828" cy="-173208.391" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505539.487" cy="-173329.777" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505536.356" cy="-173330.301" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505534.356" cy="-173330.395" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505531.55" cy="-173330.442" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505503.699" cy="-173263.673" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505502.516" cy="-173343.422" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505502.479" cy="-173343.223" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505502.464" cy="-173330.673" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505502.448" cy="-173343.045" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505502.301" cy="-173342.223" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505502.202" cy="-173338.972" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505502.186" cy="-173339.37" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505496.667" cy="-173247.771" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505496.259" cy="-173312.237" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505494.84" cy="-173247.714" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505493.337" cy="-173271.145" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505491.348" cy="-173242.174" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505491.348" cy="-173242.221" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505491.316" cy="-173244.033" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505491.107" cy="-173247.928" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505491.039" cy="-173249.63" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505491.028" cy="-173250.237" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505491.018" cy="-173251.107" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505490.997" cy="-173253.285" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505490.986" cy="-173254.196" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505490.986" cy="-173254.306" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505490.122" cy="-173257.154" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505488.573" cy="-173311.823" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505487.672" cy="-173247.583" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505486.646" cy="-173277.8" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505486.143" cy="-173249.729" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505486.091" cy="-173250.813" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505486.075" cy="-173251.494" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505486.054" cy="-173253.463" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505485.986" cy="-173255.149" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505485.981" cy="-173255.29" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505485.75" cy="-173278.616" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505484.708" cy="-173311.608" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505483.85" cy="-173280.569" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505480.938" cy="-173244.389" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505480.881" cy="-173249.572" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505480.834" cy="-173250.892" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505480.771" cy="-173252.662" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505480.766" cy="-173253.431" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505480.734" cy="-173255.96" r="1.1"/>
    <circle cx="-505480.493" cy="-173309.671" r="1.1"/>
</g>
```

When I use Illustrator to Unite the Circles, it looks like this(as you can see, it's much smaller):

```
<g clip-path="url(#a)" transform="translate(353688.12 120977.663) scale(.695)" fill="none" stroke="#a1c3cc">
    <path d="M-942472.56-471233.662H942477.89h-5.236V471233.714H-942477.89h5.236V-470191.752" stroke-width=".1"/>
    <path d="M-942477.796-172787.596H942477.796M-507890.812 471238.898V-471238.898" stroke-width="1.1"/>
</g>
```

Is there anything out there that will do this for me? Or anything faster than doing it the way I mentioned? Maybe this is something Snap.svg can do that I just can't figure out?

Comment: Write an XSLT transform that will read in the circles and spit out the paths. I doubt anyone is going to do that for you but if you try it and get stuck you could ask specific questions about it.

Comment: This is not really a programming question, also I think it should be moved to superuser.com. But, depending on the version of Illustrator, there is an option to "select">"same">"shape", that could help.

Comment: Bit confused by your svg examples, they don't see, to match up ?

Comment: @Ian They are different groups of points, I should have made them the same but I was just trying to show what I was talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if it may be possible to do it with some js, IMHO Illustrator (the tool you already use) gives you a way to do it.  *(or if they don't **give it** it's possible)*

From what I understand, you already have a structure like this, but repeated a thousand time:

[image: snapshot of Illustrator with a mockup of the problem]

Then what you want to do is to use the **unite** tool from Illustrator's **pathfinders** for each of the group.

So let Illustrator do it for you.

- Create an action : `Window > Actions > Create New Action` *(at the bottom right of the newly opened panel)*. Set its name. Then it begins to record what you are doing, so keep an eye on the popup panel to avoid undesirable things to happen.
- Select the first group, as it is in the snapshot below. Apply to it the **unite pathfinder**.
- Select the next group, but in order to save it in our batch Action, **use the `Select > Next Object Below`.** Make sure the select action has been saved in the Actions panel : [image: Illustrator Actions panel]
- Then you can stop recording by clicking the square at bottom left.
- Now, either you choose to click the play button a thousand times, either you make a script to do it.
  It seems that Adobe's ExtendScript can't call actions nor Pathfinder tool… So, you will have to use AppleScript if you're on a mac, or VBscript on win.

I don't know VB but here is the AppleScript, you'll get the logic.

```applescript
tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
    activate
    set x to count group items of document 1
    repeat x times
        do script "Your Awesome Action" from "Default Actions"
    end repeat
end tell
```

Execute this script from AppleScript Editor, *(with your document still opened and a not yet united group selected)* wait a moment, and you're done.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head man! Unfortunately, I'm not on Mac. I just set the action to execute using F10 and made AutoHotKey press it every 5 seconds. It was done in under an hour. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are after really, and not sure it will be that much smaller, representing a circle as a path, it ultimately contains more info in the path string, but you do get rid of some markup (and dom elements maybe). So not sure if this type of thing is what you're after, but may give some idea...

Lets suppose you have some circles..

```
<svg id="svg" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <circle cx="50.202" cy="50.972" r="10.1"/>
   <circle cx="40.186" cy="50.37" r="10.1"/>
   <circle cx="30" cy="50.771" r="10.1"/>
</svg>
```

You could iterate through them with Snap and build a string, like this..

```
Snap.plugin( function( Snap, Element, Paper, global ) {
        Paper.prototype.circlePathString = function(cx,cy,r) {
            var p = "M" + cx + "," + cy;
            p += "m" + -r + ",0";
            p += "a" + r + "," + r + " 0 1,0 " + (r*2) +",0";
            p += "a" + r + "," + r + " 0 1,0 " + -(r*2) + ",0";
            return p;
        };
});

var s = Snap("#svg");
var totalPath = '';
var circles = s.selectAll('circle');

circles.forEach( function( el ) {
   totalPath += s.circlePathString( el.attr('cx'), el.attr('cy'),    el.attr('r') );
   el.remove();
} );

var newCirclePath = s.path( totalPath ).attr({ fill: 'red' });
alert( s.innerSVG() );
```

You'd have to loop through each group and add the new path, but it could be useful. I'm not sure if illustrator is doing something else clever to reduce the size, or if there's a simpler way of representing a circle in a path, (or if I'm just missing the point), so this may not be enough, but could help someone else.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6bok4cyp/3/)

Comment: Good to know for sure, I will play with it and see what I get. However, I'm sure the file will still be too large... And I should have definitely been more clear in my question, Illustrator combines all of the circles that are touching into one blob of a shape, it doesn't keep the path of each individual circle.

Comment: @RugerSR9 then, depending on the version of Illustrator, there is an option to "select">"same">"shape", that could help you.

Comment: @Kaiido I read that above, sorry I didn't reply. That doesn't help me because all of the circles are already in a layer together, so it is easy to select the layers. But there is 700+ of them which would take forever to go through one-by-one. Each layer has to stay seperate because they have to be different colors.